# Vite 5 не правильно прокладывает путь после билда

Tags: css, vite

Я использую css файлик в котором подключаю шрифт вот так:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fredoka';
    src: url('../fonts/Fredoka-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

После с таким vite конфигом билдим его в /public/build

```js
export default {
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                popup: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/popup.css'), //это тот ксс файлик
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
                chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]'
            }
        },
        assetsInlineLimit: 0,
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {},
    },
    publicDir: false,
};
```

Он туда забилдит и ксс файл и шрифт, они будут находиться в одной папке(/public/build) но путь к шрифту он проложит не верно, добавив в начало '/' для ксс функции url() хотя если я сам зайду в этот файл и уберу этот слеш всё будет нормально. В чём проблема?